# New Samsung S6 tablet stuck on Samsung logo?

Tags: samsung, reboot, samsung-galaxy-s-6, android-10

I have bought 20 Samsung s6 and after every 4 of them got stuck on Samsung logo, I keep them on charging for 2 days. Nothing work for me.

Comment: Are you sure the devices are genuine? May be you bought some fake devices that can only show the Samsung logo. Have you tried pressing the power button for 10-60 seconds to force a reboot?

Comment: @Robert yes I have tried that, and I bought these devices from authentic manufactures in my country. out of 20 devices 15 are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 5 of the Samsung tablets you received are working differently than the other 15 tablets, it's clear that either:

1. Samsung has sold you a bunch of defective tablets.
2. You received at least some counterfeit tablets.

In the comments, you mentioned that you believe you purchased them from a reliable source.  If they are genuine, your experience indicates Samsung has a quality control issue... perhaps a serious one.

Return the tablets for replacements or insist on a full refund.

Note that I've purchased multiple Samsung Android products with serious problems, and trying to get support from Samsung was time consuming and a huge hassle. I now try to avoid Android devices made by Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

If they're new, I'd return them for an exchange.  (And make sure you're not getting cheap fake copies of Samsungs.)

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually return those tablets back to Samsung, and now they return me back and they are working fine.